# Is it possible to contract a virus on Ubuntu/Debian from an Apache Nutch web crawl?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, web, debian

For the fourth time now I have contracted a virus while doing a large web crawl on webmd.com. I'm not certain that this is where the virus is coming from but I don't see what else it could be.

Is it possible to get a virus this way? By doing a web crawl?

Comment: Crawling just means getting the data. The important question is, "what are you doing with the data once you get it?"

Comment: Is the virus just a file on your disk, and some AV flags it?  Or is it actually a malicious process?

Comment: @ndrix he was infected (from previous question)

Comment: With the data I am parsing it and putting it into an elasticsearch database. I'm not seeing a possible way to be infected from this but I'm not sure what else it could be. This is the only thing the server is being used for. @schroeder

Comment: @ndrix the virus is live and tearing through my CPU.

Comment: I'd look closely at the "parsing" process. But I'm not sure that the crawling is the highest likely infection vector.

Comment: Are brute force attacks easy to execute? Maybe I could prevent this by switching over to SSH keys instead of using a raw password. But my password is sufficiently long so I thought a brute force was impossible. (Sorry to bother you with this. Just trying to absorb information.)